# Android button or TextView vertical align

Tags: android, vertical-alignment

i am trying to vertically align a button or a textview, but i can't.
Neither `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"` nor `android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"` works. Not even `android:gravity="center"` does the trick.
They only aligns the object horizontally. How can i align it to the center or bottom of the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the parent layout. If you're using a RelativeLayout, you can simply use `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, although `layout_gravity="bottom"` should work as well. Keep in mind the size of this parent layout as well. You can't use `alignParentBottom` if the RelativeLayout is set to `wrap_content` for height. It should be set to `fill_parent`. You should post the rest of your XML if you're still having issues.